# Can Google Endpoints be used as an API gateway for a SaaS product?

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, ibm-api-management

I have gone through the documentation on Endpoints and Quotas, but I still cannot figure out what the scope of Google Endpoints is.

Since I don't know a better way to phrase it, let's take the example of a SaaS company that, for a monthly fee, will provide customers with stock data through a REST API. They have different packages, from `Enthusiast` (for $10 per month) to `Enterprise` (for $1000 per month).

- Would Google Endpoints be a suitable API management tool for this fictitious company?
- Can you create an interface for API token management?
- Can you set quotas based on the package that your customers are paying for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

product manager for Google Cloud Endpoints here.

We do not have quite the feature set that you need yet. We've got some features in the works (you'd need developer portals with log-in and key generation and monthly quotas) as we work on alignment with our Apigee product. There will be some progress this year, but no dates that I can speak of yet.